# Laravel : get user id null tested by postman from Json data

Tags: php, json, laravel, postman

I am trying to create an API by Laravel ,I made tables and Models and controllers ,in one of my Controllers I have this method :

```php
public function order(Request $request)
{
    $datas = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
            
    $insert = Order::create(
        [
            'user_id'=>$request->user_id,
//            'user_id'=>$datas->user_id,
            'status'=>'ordered',
        ]);
}
```

and I tested it by postman by sending list of data like this as raw in Body panel :-

```json
[
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "details": [
            {
                "product_id": 1,
                "quantity": 4
            },
            {
                "product_id": 2,
                "quantity": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

when I tested it I get the error `'user_id' cannot be null`; and when I use the commented line above I get `Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object in file`.

Comment: what is the output after using `dd($request)`?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG I will add both of request and datas dd now

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG I added what you asked

Comment: you are passing in format of array of object means if you do `$datas[0]['user_id']` you should get your user id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an array and then decoding it, so you need to indicate which array element you want to use. In addition, passing `true` as second argument to `json_decode` returns an array and not an object. So something like this should work:

```php
public function order(Request $request)
{
    $datas = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        
    $insert = Order::create([
        'user_id' => $datas[0]['user_id'],
        'status'=>'ordered',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas enviando un objeto dentro de una arreglo, envia el objeto sin estar dentro del arreglo es decir:

```
{
     "user_id": 1,
        "details": [
            {
                "product_id": 1,
                "quantity": 4
            },
            {
                "product_id": 2,
                "quantity": 3
            }
        ]
    }
```